# How to wait till some actions completed when its invoking Async APIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

We have some set of actions but, each actions invokes Async APIs.  We want wait till Async API got back and then start execution of second action.

Ex: We have X, Y and Z actions: Method1 does X action and method2 does Y action and Method3 does Z action. Here Method1 internally calls some Async API. So we don't want invoke Method2 until Method1 complete.

```
method1 ()

// Here wait till method1 complete 

method2 ()

// Here wait till method12 complete 

method3 ()
```

---

```
method 1 
{
    block{
             // This block will be called by Async API 
          };

   // here invoking Async API
}
```

What can be used to wait till method1 complete. Which mechanism of Objective-C is more efficient?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may use operation queues for that purposes  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1

Comment: Thanks for reply, Any other suggestions...

Comment: and you do not have any didfinish kind of delegates as well?

Comment: No we don't have any didFinish kind of delegates Ishank

Comment: Are method1,2,3 private API, or you can change them?

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke your methods in the main thread, because Async API processes in the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dispatch_semaphore_t`, which you signal at the end of your blocks (the asynchronous completion blocks). Furthermore, if method1, method2, method3 always get called in sequence then they need to share the semaphore and I would move the whole thing to as single method. Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
- (void) method123
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t waitSema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    callAsynchAPIPart1WithCompletionBlock(^(void) {
        // Do your completion then signal the semaphore
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(waitSema);
    });

    // Now we wait until semaphore is signaled.
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(waitSema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); 

    callAsynchAPIPart2WithCompletionBlock(^(void) {
        // Do your completion then signal the semaphore
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(waitSema);
    });

    // Now we wait until semaphore is signaled.
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(waitSema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); 

    callAsynchAPIPart3WithCompletionBlock(^(void) {
        // Do your completion then signal the semaphore
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(waitSema);
    });

    // Now we wait until semaphore is signaled.
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(waitSema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); 

    dispatch_release(waitSema);
}
```

Alternately, you can chain your calls through your completion blocks as follows:

```
- (void) method123
{
    callAsynchAPIPart1WithCompletionBlock(^(void) {
        // Do completion of method1 then call method2
        callAsynchAPIPart2WithCompletionBlock(^(void) {
            // Do completion of method2 then call method3
            callAsynchAPIPart1WithCompletionBlock(^(void) {
                // Do your completion
            });
        });
    });
}
```